# Excel: How to skip specific rows when importing a CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I want to skip the header and last rows when importing a CSV into Excel, just like I can skip specific columns. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power Query will do this for you. It's a free add-on from Microsoft that helps you import data and munge it. ( it'll become part of the excel core features in the future so it's worth getting to know now.)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you on? It would be relative easy to pre-process the file with `head` or `tail` to generate a CSV with your undesirable lines missing.

```
tail -n +3 myfile.csv | head -n 10 > subset.csv
```

This would take 10 lines starting at line 3 (lines 3-12), for example, and save it to the file `subset.csv`

Answer (score -1):

If you skip columns you are probably using the Import Wizard. If so,  you can tick "My Data has Headers" in Step 1 to ignore the first row.

The Wizard does not have any built-in functionality to skip rows. It might be faster to import all rows and manually delete the first and last one.

Comment: nope. what if he has 100,000 rows with 1000 columns?

Comment: @Yuck  Nope what? What if he has? What's 100,000 rows? Excel can handle ten times as many.  He can still import all rows and delete the first and last one. Instead of downvoting, offer something better.

Comment: it won't fit into memory of an ordinary computer

Comment: @Yuck can you substantiate that? Based on your perception of Excel's capabilities in a very unlikely scenario you downvote?